# Swift - Why is protocol still treated as generic even though where clause has specialized the associated type?

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance, protocols, where-clause

I have a generic protocol:

```
protocol GenericProtocol {
  associatedtype GenericParameter
}
```

I'm not able to use it like this:

```
var someValue: GenericProtocol?
```

I get the error message we all know well:

> Protocol 'GenericProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Having run into this error many times and having spent a long time pondering the conceptual reason for this error, I think I have grasped it at least somewhat. What I don't understand, is why I can't create a protocol which inherits from and specializes my generic protocol such that it can be used in type signatures. Here is the inheriting protocol:

```
protocol ConcreteProtocol: GenericProtocol where GenericParameter == Bool { }
```

But even this I can't use in a type signature:

```
var someValue: ConcreteProtocol?
```

> Protocol 'ConcreteProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Am I misunderstanding the meaning of a `where` clause? What is the conceptual reason that even constrained sub-protocols must be treated as generic? I am sure that this is not a bug but rather a purposeful fact of the language which is known to the Swift community. Can anyone explain this to me?

Also if anyone could provide a way in which I can to achieve what I want that would be much appreciated, though I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: There is a good read about them here https://www.bobthedeveloper.io/blog/generic-protocols-with-associated-type

Answer (score 1):

```
var someValue: GenericProtocol?
```

Why this doesn’t work is quite obvious if you think of trying

```
var someValue: Class = Class1()
someValue            = Class2()
```

The point is that you have a protocol which is for every type you assign there different, has different method types for example, which makes `someValue` unusable.

```
protocol ConcreteProtocol: GenericProtocol where GenericParameter == Bool { }
var someValue: ConcreteProtocol?
```

does likely not work because classes may want to override the `associatedtype` and so could not be assigned to `someValue`. So implementing this in the language would probably deny classes to override, since `ConcreteProtcol` could use `GenericParameter == Bool` in one of its extensions already.

Comment: If I understand correctly you’re saying that what I’ve written provides a default value for the associated type, but that since that default associated type can be overridden by the conforming type the compiler still cannot assume that it knows `GenericParameter == Bool`. This makes sense, but I feel like it should apply only if I had used a typealias in an extension to provide this default value - I think that it would make more sense that since I specified the associated type in the very definition of the protocol using a where clause it is not subject to change by the conforming type.

Comment: Another guess is that `someValue` should still be usable as `GenericProtocol` since it implements that too, but it can’t, since `can only be used as a generic constraint`. A generic constraint is probably a class implementing the protocol or a generic(class?!) paramter constrained to implement the protocol.